# Necessity of convolution operations for product of two polynomials via brute force method

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, polynomials, multiplication

Reference: Page 4 of this [document](http://algorithm.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~course/Extra_Info/Divide%20and%20Conquer_supplement.pdf)

Given two polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ each of degree $n$ represented in coefficient form, it takes $\mathcal{\Theta}(n)$ time to evaluate given some input $x$.

In the reference linked, in order to get product of these two polynomials, $c(x) = p(x)q(x)$, via brute force, we have to compute new coefficients via convolution $\left(c_k = \sum_{i=0}^k a_i b_{k-i} \right)$ which takes $\mathcal{\Theta}(n^2)$ time.

However, if we wanted to evaluate this product with some given input $x$, we can evaluate the two polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ separately and then multiply the two scalar results. Overall, this would take $\mathcal{\Theta}(n)$ time for two evaluations and a scalar multiplication. This lets us avoid having to do convolutions and would be faster than $\mathcal{\Theta}(n^2)$.

**Question**: When it comes to evaluation of the product of two polynomials, is it actually $\mathcal{\Theta}(n)$ using the method above or are we somehow still doomed to $\mathcal{\Theta}(n^2)$?

I'm aware there's a faster way to do this in $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ time via Fast Fourier Transform, but I'm more curious about the necessity of the convolution calculations. I suspect it's more if we care about getting the coefficients of the product than the actual evaluation, as in we more care about knowing $\{c_0, c_1, c_2, \dotsc\}$ than $c(x) = p(x)q(x)$.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.  If you're asking how to get the coefficients of the product polynomial $p(x) q(x)$, you already know how to do it -- use the FFT; it takes $O(n \log n)$ time.  What more is there to say?  What is your question?

Comment: I wasn't asking what the typical/fast method was to find the coefficients of a product of two polynomials. I was asking whether the evaluation/calculation of the product of two polynomials $c(x) = p(x)q(x)$ given an input $x$ is $\mathcal{\Theta}(n)$ instead of $\mathcal{\Theta}(n^2)$ from directly computing the coefficients of $c(x)$ followed by its evaluation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two polynomials $P_n(x)$, $Q_n(x)$, you can obviously calculate the value $P_n(x) · Q_n(x)$ in $O(n)$ for every x. The document asks about calculating the coefficients, which is a very different question. If all you want is to evaluate $P_n(x) · Q_n(x)$ for various values of x, then calculating the coefficients of the product polynomial isn't actually useful on current processors (due to latency, you can usually calculate two polynomials of degree n in parallel in practically the same time as one, and almost twice as fast as one polynomial of degree 2n). However, there are situations where the coefficients are *exactly* what you want.

As the document says, the coefficients can be calculated using FFT in $O (n log n)$. A straightforward divide-and-conquer method doesn't improve on the trivial $O(n^2)$. The document mentions a more clever divide-and-conquer method that multiplies polynomials of degree $2^k$ in $O (3^k)$. Knuth's "Art of Computer Programming" has an improvement on this which multiplies polynomials of degree $m^k$ in $O ((2m-1)^k)$, for every fixed m, but with constant factors growing quite quickly.

Comment: Thanks. I selected your answer since it answered two points: that the product of two polynomials can be evaluated in $\mathcal{O}(n)$ and that calculating the coefficients of that that product is a different problem from calculating/evaluating that product given some input $x$.

Comment: @instantwipe2000, precision of language is important in maths. The "*product of two polynomials*" is a polynomial: to evaluate the product of two polynomials is to explicitly find that polynomial - although what *that* means is a matter of representation. I think the failure to distinguish clearly between evaluating the product of two polynomials vs evaluating their product *at a point* is why D.W. wasn't sure what you were asking. I wasn't entirely sure either, but my aim was to give you the understanding to answer your question yourself. Perhaps I should have made that clearer.

Comment: (And for the avoidance of doubt, I'm not complaining about you selecting this as the accepted answer: you should select the one which helps you more. Rather I'm hoping to promote clear communication of mathematics).

Answer (score 3):

> In the reference linked, in order to get product of these two polynomials, $c(x) = p(x)q(x)$, via brute force, we have to compute new coefficients via convolution $\left(c_k = \sum_{i=0}^k a_i b_{k-i} \right)$ which takes $\mathcal{\Theta}(n^2)$ time.

That's not what it says. It says firstly that **convolution is equivalent to polynomial multiplication** (i.e. an algorithm for convolution is also an algorithm for polynomial multiplication and vice versa); and secondly that

> The direct approach is to compute all $c_k$ using the formula above

and that **this approach** has complexity $\Theta(n^2)$. The FFT approach calculates a convolution (and indeed, the continuous Fourier transform produces a convolution of two functions: the convolution of two coefficient sequences is a discrete analogue).